# Difference between object reference declaration and object construction?

Tags: java

Consider a class named `Calculator` with the following code:

```
class Calc extends Calculator {

    Calculator calculator;                    // [Style 1]

    Calculator calculator = new Calculator(); // [Style 2]
}
```

To my knowledge, no memory has been allocated in `[1]`, but in statement `[2]` a new `Calculator` object is created.

Are there any other differences beyond that?

Answer (score 6):

When you write

```
Calculator calculator;
```

It only means that you're declaring a reference to the object of type `Calculator`. Reference is not an object, so memory is not allocated.

When you write

```
new Calculator();
```

It constructs the object of type `Calculator` and returns a reference to this object.

So, when you write

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
```

It means that you construct the object and store a reference to it in `calculator`.

'calculator' is not an object, it's only a reference to this object. You can have more than 1 reference to the same object.

**Update**:
Regarding the title of this topic, *creating the instance of class* and *creating the object* are absolutely the same. What you mean is, I believe, *declaring a reference to object* vs *declaring it with inplace assignment* (though I'm not exactly sure about terms) :-)

Answer (score 3):

`Calculator calculator;`- its the definition of the variable **calculator**.. you tell the compiler that it can hold variable of type **Calculator** and nothing else. and it has null now and nothing is assigned..

`Calculator calculator = new Calculator();--`this actually stores **reference to Calculatore object** created in heap to **calculator** variable. and now it stores a variable which is called **initialisation.**

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, no object **Calculator** is created, and the value of the variable is **null**.

Answer (score 0):

Value of the first reference is null, and second one points to the objects. Also, if you have non-default constructor for Calculator class (with some side-effects, like logging, for example), it is not called in the first case.